# CosmosDB is returning more than the default number of records

Tags: azure, go, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using go1.18 and [go-cosmosdb](https://github.com/vippsas/go-cosmosdb) to fetch records from CosmosDB:

```
opts := cosmosapi.QueryDocumentsOptions{
    IsQuery:              true,
    ContentType:          cosmosapi.QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE,
    ConsistencyLevel:     cosmosapi.ConsistencyLevelStrong,
    EnableCrossPartition: false,
}

resp, err := c.client.QueryDocuments(ctx, DatabaseName, ContainerName, query, &res, opts)
```

The query is a simple select * query.

Since I'm not setting opts.MaxItemCount, it should default to 0, and the returned documents should be up to a 100 according to the [azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api):

> Query requests support pagination through the x-ms-max-item-count and
> x-ms-continuation request headers. The x-ms-max-item-count header
> specifies the maximum number of values that can be returned by the
> query execution. This can be between 1 and 1000, and is configured
> with a default of 100.

But it weirdly returns more than a 100. I'm not sure if this is a new change? I'm pretty sure I used this before and it used to return only a hundred records.
Any thoughts?

Comment: The change feed can go above the specified limit if more than the configured number of items have changed in a given transaction. Could this be similar?